# Can someone in the 3rd world invest in the US Stock Market online using PayPal?

Tags: stocks, investing

In the past, I wanted to earn money from the internet and I came across too many scam websites that give money for clicking ads or mining bitcoins. I no longer trust the third party websites and I would like to ask if it's possible to invest my PayPal balance in the USA stock market using a website provided by the government or official organizations.

I googled and I can only find the third party websites.

Comment: Can you edit to clarify the issue? I think you are conflating 2 issues. You wish to invest in US companies. Inserting PayPal in the mix makes little sense. When I want to send my broker money, I transfer it from my savings/checking, either directly, or via check.

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica I wasn't aware of the issue of PayPal. I thought It's an acceptable payment method just like the check and the bank transfer. My question is: Does the government provide a service like that (It's the most trusted as I think)? If no, how can I make sure that this is a trusted US company as I only know their website?

Comment: Are there no Stock Brokers that advertise in your country? In the US, Fidelity, Schwab, eTrade, Robinhood, the list is long. SE is world wide, of course, but for non-US answers, especially here (Money.SE) you'd need to disclose the country.

Comment: @user2824371 You usually don't buy stocks via the Government, but via stock brokers.